# How to wait until other script is ready?

Tags: godot

I have two scripts, first is AsteroidSpawner script that literally spawns object named Asteroid, and second is HUD that control all UI related stuffs.

There are some labels in UI, so I used onready to get those nodes:

```
extends CanvasLayer

class_name HUD

onready var asteroids_label = $Control/RightContainer/AsteroidCountLabel

func set_asteroids_label(value: float):
    asteroids_label.text = "Asteroids: " + str(value)
    pass
```

However, when I try to access HUD script, with setasteroidlabel, it gives me null error:

```
var spawned_asteroids: Array = []
onready var hud: HUD = get_tree().get_root().find_node("HUD", true, false)

func _ready():
    spawn_asteroids()

func spawn_asteroids():
    ... spawn asteroid ...

    spawned_asteroids.push_back(asteroid_instance)

    hud.set_asteroids_label(spawned_asteroids.size()) # UPDATE HUD
```

> Invalid set index 'text' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'String'

I guess that HUD is not ready, but AsteroidSpawner script try to accessing it, wasn't it? Then how should I wait until HUD is loaded?

Comment: What does your node tree look like? What scripts are attached to what nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `await` until it's ready:

```
func _ready():
   await hud.ready # Godot 4
   hud.set_asteroids_label(spawned_asteroids.size()) # Works
```

In earlier versions of Godot, you can use `yield` instead:

```
func _ready():
    yield(hud, "ready")
    hud.set_asteroids_label(spawned_asteroids.size()) # Works
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid set index 'text' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'String'` indicates that the issue is with `$Control/RightContainer/AsteroidCountLabel`, *not* `et_tree().get_root().find_node("HUD", true, false)`. Make sure that you actually have the correct path to `AsteroidCountLabel` within the HUD.

One easy way to do this is by selecting the node in the editor and pressing `Ctrl+C` -- this will copy the relative node path to your clipboard, so you can paste it into the script.

You could also export a var of type `NodePath` from your HUD and set it to the path of the label in the editor.

Comment: That was correct path. It actually works if I wait until AsteroidCountLabel is not null.